# How to call MvxViewModel from Xamarin Android Activity?

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

How can I call `MvxViewModel` from my xamarin android `Activity` class? In my situation, I can't do like that `local: MvxBind=" Click MethodFromMvxViewModel"` to get to `MvxViewModel`.

**So my situation is:**

I have a Facebook login. In my activity, I have two options when trying to log in. If user has emailed in his Facebook account, I get some info about user and want to save it to database and if user does not have email in Facebook account, I open new content view with form to fill with email and press save button and after save button is pressed I need to save user to db.

**The code of activity:**

```
[Activity(Label = "Facebook login")]
class FacebookLoginView : MvxActivity, IFacebookCallback, GraphRequest.IGraphJSONObjectCallback
{
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private ICallbackManager callbackManager;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.FacebookLoginView);

        loginButton = FindViewById<LoginButton>(Resource.Id.loginButton1);
        loginButton.SetReadPermissions(new string[] { "user_friends", "email" });
        callbackManager = CallbackManagerFactory.Create();
        loginButton.RegisterCallback(callbackManager, this);
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.OnActivityResult(requestCode, (int)resultCode, data);
    }

    public void OnCancel()
    {
        //Does nothing, just closes facebook login screen
    }

    public void OnError(FacebookException error)
    {
        //For now does nothing
    }

    public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        var loginresult = result as LoginResult;

        GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.NewMeRequest(loginresult.AccessToken, this);
        graphRequest.Parameters.PutString("fields", "id,name,email");
        graphRequest.ExecuteAsync();

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SlideListView);
    }

    public void OnCompleted(JSONObject @object, GraphResponse response)
    {
        var facebookId = (long)@object.Get("id");
        var email = @object.Get("email").ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {               
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CompleteRegistrationView);
            //GetEmail from form
        }
        //save user
    }
}
```

In the last method `OnCompleted` I want to call `MvxViewModel` and send him **email** and **facebookId**. How can I do that from `Activity`?

Comment: you have ViewModel property in MvxActivity so try: `((YourViewModel)this.ViewModel).YourMethod()`

Answer (score 1):

If you use a generic `MvxActivity<MyViewModel>` you will be able to call any method on your ViewModel.

```
public void OnCompleted(JSONObject @object, GraphResponse response)
{
    var facebookId = (long)@object.Get("id");
    var email = @object.Get("email").ToString();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
    {               
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CompleteRegistrationView);
        //GetEmail from form
    }
    //save user
    ViewModel.SaveUserMethod(object);
}
```